# Word request - silently judge?

Tags: word-request

What is the word for silently trying to understand a person from his/her talk, and his/her mental situation behind his/her action or talk?

Say for example I was talking to a old friend, I met after a long time. But she was not talking truth, that was evident from her talk. I tried to understood why without asking her, and also tried to understand what was truly behind all her talking?

Answer (score 1):

Though it's used mainly in the context of writing, you may, for our ease, twist it a little to have an idiom for what you want. However, ***there could be many options*** and it depends which one you want to use.

Here is what I think something ***close*** to your concern of *knowing/understanding* something which is not clearly said/told/written.

> While she was speaking her way, I simply [*read between the lines*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33753/word-request-silently-judge). It was clear from her talk that she's hiding the truth.

Surprisingly, TheFreeDictionary quotes the too close a thing that you referred in your question.

> *After listening to what she said, if you **read between the lines,** you can begin to see what she really means.*

Answer (score 0):

A few options might be:

```
- Interpret
- See what was behind her words
- Analyze
- Unearth
- Uncover (his/her intention)
- Read between the lines
- Infer
```

Also, if I were to read your paragraph, this statement jumps out at me: **But she was not talking truth, that was evident from her talk.** To me it would seem like you need to either (1) qualify this statement with something like `I could tell she wasn't telling the truth.` Or `I thought she wasn't telling the truth.` Or (2) explain why no qualification is necessary, such as `She said she had stopped eating red meat, but the hamburger that was in her hand indicated she was obviously lying.`